# Building Connection from Android to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

Hi guys I'm building a Login and Register app from android studio and whenever I run the app I get no errors but the app is not connecting to the PHP itself, I tried to change the address of the URL but everytime I change it, there's an error but whenever I use my IP and the address of the php I got no error but there's no response to the process of php and the process of android, am I using the right address or should I change it?

Here's my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText etNumber, etPassword;
private String phone, password;
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.218/login/login.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    phone ="";
    password = "";
    etNumber = findViewById(R.id.username);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
}
public void backToMenu (View view){
    phone = etNumber.getText().toString().trim();
    if(!phone.equals("")){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.equals("true")) {

                    finish();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);

                } else if (response.equals("false")) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid Login ID/Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString().trim(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("phone_number", phone);
                return data;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fields cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}



public void switchRegister (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Register.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

And here's my PHP code

```
  <?php
      if(isset($_POST['phone'])){
      require_once "conn.php";
      require_once "validate.php";
      $phone = $_POST['phone'];
      $sql = "select * from users where phone_number= '$phone'";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
           echo "true";
           session_start();
           $_SESSION['phone_number'] = $row['phone_number'];
            header("location: validatepass.php?phone=$phone");

          }
            else{
    echo "false";
}

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: in your php code you should return a  json response rather than echo.

Comment: Also try with retrofit it make thing easy to handle in android

Answer (score 0):

you should use this code.

```
 <?php
  
   class Reply{

       function procced(){

           if(isset($_POST['phone']))
           {
           require_once "conn.php";
           require_once "validate.php";
           $phone = $_POST['phone'];
           $sql = "select * from users where phone_number= '$phone'";
           $result = $conn->query($sql);
             if($result->num_rows > 0)
               {
      
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['phone_number'] = $row['phone_number'];
                header("location: validatepass.php?phone=$phone");
                $data=["response"=>"success"];
                return json_encode($data);
               }
           
             else{
               $data=["response"=>"error"];
               return json_encode($data);
             }
         }

         $data=["response"=>"error"];
               return json_encode($data);
     }
```

Comment: when I use this code on php file it works both ways either my code or this one, but when I use this on my android app in basically does nothing, not even an "error", I think my problem would be the connection but even stacktrace wont show a thing, I am basically using the IP of my computer for the URL link

Comment: you should put some "Log.i()" inside the onResonse callback  for exemple inside onResponse in backToMenu methode: Log.i("RESPONSE",response) and look at the logcat in your android studio.

Comment: You also need to make sure your phone and your server are in the same network. using the same wifi for exemple. and if possible send a snapshot of the logcat after a trie

Comment: i am just using a emulator on the pc the built in emulator of the android studio i'll try to put some log on it

Comment: there's only one error on the Logs and I think it far different from my problem


the only error in the log is this one-

         2020-11-13 12:51:12.155 30916-30916/RAMS.e_wallet E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"

Comment: do get anything inside  one of volley callbacks, in onErrorResponse or onResponse?

Comment: Ok that means you have to fixe this error. May be it's an issue of the version of volley you are using now. you can also try to use other libraries like retrofit https://square.github.io/retrofit/  or  okhttp directly https://square.github.io/okhttp/ or by using this library i made on top   of it to make it very easy  https://github.com/firminApp/EasyRequestMaker .

Comment: there is only one version of volley that's available i don't think the dependencies has the problem, i'm thinking of the mapping but i don't know which will be used as the "query" or as the variable

Comment: I changed my echo to JSON and the response to JSON format the thing is I'm having an error of 
     "eorg.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1 of"

Comment: can you show what the eorg.json.JSONException message said please?

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/7LXq4QVM/Capture.png


here it is

Comment: ok right... i think it's about your json that come from your server, can share the response you get when you try in you browser for exemple